# Excel Column Pixel Width to Column Width Relationship

Tags: excel, openxlsx

I'm generating an excel workbook through the R package openxlsx and am running into a weird issue.
My goal is to replicate a template as closely as possible for reporting purposes. However the same column widths in the report I'm generating (11.71 / 86 pixels) are different from my template (11.78 / 113 pixels). If I manually adjust my 11.71 to 11.78 I get 88 pixels. I don't understand where the discrepancy between 113 and 88 pixels is coming from. I've checked that the scale value is the same, the zoom is set at the same custom level...I'm baffled as to what this derives from.

Can anyone share some insight on how the pixel size is set?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to use the same style, I invite you to have a look at `openxlsx2`. If you have a template, you can create exact clones from it. With `openxlsx` you always have to make compromises and some things, like certain column widths are simply not possible.

Comment: @JanMarvin What is openxlsx2?  There does not seem to be a package with that name in CRAN.

Comment: @G5W https://github.com/JanMarvin/openxlsx2